# Jenkins Credentials with Docker and NEXT JS no value in log

Tags: docker, jenkins, next.js, dockerfile, credentials

I'm really struggling with Jenkins and Docker to pass some variable to my Next project.
For information, my Jenkins and Docker are on my own server.

In Jenkins I created a secret text with credentials, VAR_TEST with the value "This is a test".

I did that script in pipeline :

```
pipeline {
    agent any 

    stages {
        stage('Clone Git') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: 'file:///var/git/next'
            }
        }

        stage('Stop and Remove Old Container') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def oldContainer = sh(script: 'docker ps -aq --filter name=next_container', returnStdout: true).trim()
                    if (oldContainer != '') {
                        sh 'docker stop next_container'
                        sh 'docker rm next_container'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build Docker Image') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'VAR_TEST', variable: 'VAR_TEST')]) {
                    sh '''#!/bin/sh
                    docker build --build-arg VAR_TEST="$VAR_TEST" -t next:latest .
                    '''
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run Docker Container') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'VAR_TEST', variable: 'VAR_TEST')]) {
                    sh '''#!/bin/sh
                    docker run -d -e VAR_TEST="$VAR_TEST" -p 3000:3000 --name next_container next:latest
                    '''
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Prune Docker System') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker system prune -a -f'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I create that Dockerfile :

```
# Indiquez à Docker d'attendre ces arguments lors de la construction
ARG VAR_TEST

# Utilisez une image de base Node.js
FROM node:18-alpine

# Définissez le répertoire de travail à l'intérieur du conteneur
WORKDIR /app

# Copiez le fichier package.json dans le répertoire de travail
COPY package*.json ./

# Installez les dépendances du projet
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install

# Copiez tous les fichiers du projet dans le répertoire de travail
COPY . .

# Transformez les arguments en variables d'environnement pour que votre application puisse les utiliser
ENV VAR_TEST=$VAR_TEST

# Affichage de la variable (pour le débogage)
RUN echo $VAR_TEST

# Construisez l'application
RUN npm run build

# Supprimez les dépendances de développement après la construction
RUN npm prune --production

# Exposez le port sur lequel votre application écoute (si nécessaire)
EXPOSE 3000

# Démarrez l'application lorsque le conteneur est lancé
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My Next Config looks like that :

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    VAR_TEST: process.env.VAR_TEST,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

The problem here is when I check on my server in the Container created the value of the variable, it exists, I have a good result :

```
/app # echo $VAR_TEST
This is a test
```

But when I want to log it on server side with my Next project... nothing... the value is not there :

```
 console.log('Test : ', process.env.VAR_TEST);
```

Can someone help and tell what I am doing wrong here ?

I am totally lost even after trying everything according the doc :(

A big thanks !

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally found a solution, it seems that you don't need to change your next.config.js, I let it as original and now it works !

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  /* config options here */
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Finally that post can be considered as a tuto